# Clicking menubar icon Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am making an menubar application and now I want to create function that when you press <kbd>ALT</kbd> key and then click the statusbar icon of the app. It shows all the menus that are there, some are hidden because you can toggle it by yourself. I really would like to know how I could make something like

```
if ([theappinthestatusbar = clicked]) {
    [menuitem setHidden:NO];
} else {
    [menuitem setHidden:YES];
}
```

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the delegate method `menuNeedsUpdate:` of `NSMenu` and show/hide the menu item depending on the <kbd>⌥</kbd>-Key

```
- (void)menuNeedsUpdate:(NSMenu *)aMenu
{
    NSUInteger flags = ([NSEvent modifierFlags] & NSDeviceIndependentModifierFlagsMask);
    BOOL shouldHideSecretMenu = !(flags == NSAlternateKeyMask);
    [menuitem setHidden:shouldHideSecretMenu];
}
```